# Set up multiple projects within one Git repository

Tags: git

For an application which I have been working on, we are gonna start over for a version 2. The Git Repository system is getting a bit full, so I would like to store all of the version within a single git repo.

What would be the best way to store multiple project version within one Git repository?

Comment: Do you plan on reusing _any_ of the previous code?  If not, then maybe just create a new repository.  I don't see the point of hosting the old code in the same repo.

Comment: Partical code fragments. But I would prefer to keep all of the versions within the Git repo titled the project.

Comment: I believe it is very cheap to spin up a new repo using something like Bitbucket or Github.  This is what I would do unless there is a functional reason to keep both code lines in the same repo.

Comment: If you plan to replace v1 by v2 I reccomend to use branch for v2

Comment: Ah oke @TimBiegeleisen, not really any function reason here more to keep an overview.